# Issue when connecting to open shift via mysql workbench on Mac

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mac-os-x, redhat

I am trying to connect to open shift with mysql workbench on an iMac. A colleague has shown me his setup on Windows which looks exactly as follows (other than the usernames / passwords changing)

[image]

However I keep running in to the following error and I have no idea how to fix it - I am 100% sure my password is ok, so don't really understand why it would say password yes.

[image]

Is there any special configuration differences needed between a Mac and PC setup, or any setting/config you can think of that might solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that the MySQL server is not accepting a connection for user adminM4B1hN at the given host. You need to allow such a connection for that user (e.g. by adding an anyhost user entry (adminM4B1hN@%) for that user.

Also, keep in mind how the MySQL server is seen from the remote end of your SSH tunnel. If the tunnel ends on the same machine where the MySQL runs then the MySQL server address would be localhost not what you have given. The address is always resolved relative to the remote end of the tunnel.

Answer (score -1):

The SSH Hostname must be the same as MySQL Hostname